# Long time between first and second interviews

Tags: interviewing, job-search, united-kingdom

I have recently had a first interview of a new job at a different company. That interview went well enough that I have been asked to go for a second interview. Due to the timing of this, they cannot do it for a couple of weeks, which happens to coincide with when I'm away on honeymoon, which delays it by a couple more weeks.

How badly will this impact my chances with this new role? The first two week delay is due to them, and then there's a further three week delay is caused by me. It just makes me wonder about it all.

In case it has any impact this is an engineering design roles. I have not been told what this second interview will be, but I'm guessing more technical than the first one.

Comment: having been a few search/hiring committees, I can say it's not a big deal. All of the searches have taken months. If you were applying to be a delivery driver it might matter, but for a professional it doesn't. My current job literally took 5 months from resume to first day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How badly will this impact my chances with this new role?

The only way to truly know is to ask them.

To be honest, many things can happen in three weeks, and in some cases hiring processes are faster than that (if they add a 2 week delay perhaps this is not the case here, though).

Anyways, I suggest that you **tell them about this ASAP**, so you can come up with a solution as what to do with the upcoming interview.

You may also want to keep your options open, and try to search for other job opportunities in case this delay can't be solved.

Comment: "The only way to truly know is to ask them" - exactly. We have no idea. I've had cases where I was hiring a unique role without immediate pressure, and I really wanted a specific candidate, I was willing to wait weeks to work around scheduling issues. In other cases, where I've had a stack of qualified people and wanted someone right away, the OP would get tossed out...

Comment: @dwizum agree with that. It seems likely that in this case they may be willing to wait, and this won't be a problem. But it is better to be completely sure and clear about it.